# Any way to make program run only on a performance core (P-core)?

Tags: windows, affinity, execution

I need to run a compiler, and [people have previously found that it runs well on a single core](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW-FPGA-Idea-Exchange/Multi-core-Compiling/idc-p/2301338#M297).

Now that Intel's 12th generation consumer chips have separate P-cores and E-cores, can I somehow tell the compile worker to run specifically on a P-core, so that it gets the fastest core on my machine?

Comment: Identification of which core is which is the first part of that equation then forcing your code to run there is the second. But neither is really topical for ServerFault. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68444429

Comment: Oh, I came from https://serverfault.com/questions/571516/any-way-to-make-a-program-run-on-a-specific-core-on-launch and assumed it's the apt Stack Exchange. Sorry. Could you please suggest which will be appropriate? @diya

Comment: I think it is more of a programming question and thus topical on stack over flow

Comment: @eccentricOrange Then you also saw the link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759948/set-affinity-with-start-affinity-command-on-windows-7 in the question you linked.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I did, but that doesn't tell you about P-cores vs E-cores, and I couldn't find a reliable way to get that info